# Super basic Q: How to regulate voltage in this basic circuit to avoid damaging the heating plate?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, basic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCwUEO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
This is for a teen-level science fair type project. 
Materials include this [3V-12V generator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B078MSFFH5) and this [5V 1W heating plate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XR46HKM)

**Goal**: 12V generator, turned by propeller or crank, heats a 5 V heating plate to up to 120 F.

**Problem 1**: What component(s) must / should be added to the circuit to regulate the voltage to prevent exceeding 5V and (presumably) damaging the heating plate?

**Problem 2**: The device is intended to be hand-held and mobile, and thus sometimes not grounded during power generation. Is it necessary to ground it to prevent charge build-up (and shock to someone handling it)? If so, how?

Thanks, in advance, for any guidance for these basic and fundamental questions!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. It takes about 48 volts DC or 36 VAC to be considered a shock hazard. 12 volts posses no shock hazard, assuming generator is always has a load of some type.

Comment: Thanks! So if it was run at full speed for some time, a dangerous charge should not build up? I am assuming it would zero out pretty quickly after stopping, but I'm not sure. Any thoughts on what, if anything, needs to be added to prevent damage to the heating plate?

Comment: If would have to be posted as an 'answer', and we have no details of your heating plate, as in current/wattage rating. Voltage rating. Maybe a picture of it. We do not like to guess.

Comment: Here's a [link](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XR46HKM/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) Does that provide enough info?

Comment: not enough info.  you need heatsink 0r baseplate and sensor with controller then mass of object being heated then ok. 1 watt wont keep coffee warm but will defrost mirror.  temp rise = Pd*Rth

Comment: BTW: You may need some gearing to get that thing up to the RPM needed to crank out 12V.

Comment: That's something I can actually do on my own!

Answer (score 2):

Go back on amazon and look for 5V buck-regulators... One like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0129HYAW0) will do.

[image]

Hook the IN side to the generator and the 5V side to the heater through a switch You will need
a voltmeter to adjust the output to 5V one time. Adding an LED with a 330R resistor in series with it , in parallel with the heater would also be a nice feature. You should also add a diode before the regulator to protect it when you crank the generator the wrong way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4K7xb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> Problem 2: The device is intended to be hand-held and mobile, and thus sometimes not grounded during power generation. Is it necessary to ground it to prevent charge build-up (and shock to someone handling it)? If so, how?

Well the only charge buildup that may happen is if the crank mechanism builds up static electricity. Otherwise the voltage you get will be whatever the generator creates when you crank it. So grounding is not required.

Comment: @RedOrm see update.

Comment: Thanks so much for the drawing the circuit. Super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The generator is DC output and the heating element could care less if it is AC or DC powered.

As for voltage regulation: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LM7805.pdf

This IC mounted to a small heat sink will work fine. 1 watt at 5 volts is only 200 mA, well within the LM7805 1 amp rating. The uA7805 is the same IC made by another manufacture. Look at the pdf and notice the small bypass capacitors on the input and output.

Put those together on a PCB and you are ready to go. The IC has over-temperature and over-current limiting built in.

NOTE: The generator (-) or common is connected to the regulator common, and connected to one of the heater wires. The generator (+) output connects to the LM7805 input. The LM7805 output connects to the other heater wire. No chassis ground needed.

Comment: But then you don't need the heater element... +1 anyway though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Question: Do I simply add this in series with the line into the heater plate? What do I connect the common pin to if the device is not going to be grounded?

Comment: The regulator common/ground terminal connects to the negative side of the generator, and to one terminal of the heater.

Comment: The generator (-) or common is connected to the regulator common, and connected to one of the heater wires. The generator (+) output connects to the LM7805) input. The LM7805 output connects to the other heater wire. No chassis ground needed.

Comment: @RedOrm be aware with this type of linear regulator any extra power you crank in gets dissipated in the regulator/heatsink. If you get it up to 12V that will be 1.4W dissipated to wasted heat. Hence my not needing the heater element comment. Switching regulator is much much more efficient.

Comment: This is so helpful, All. I really appreciate it!

Comment: This circuit also needs the reverse generator diode.